# flat list function in recursive

Tags: python, recursion

Im trying to write a function that get a list, and return a flatten one, 
for example

```
a=[1,2,[3,5,(2,3)]]
print(flat(a))
[1,2,3,5,(2,3)]
```

I wrote this :

```
def flat(lst,res=[]):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return res
    else:
        for element in lst:
            if isinstance(element,list):
                res.append(flat(element))
            res.append(element)
    return res
```

but my output is :

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, (2, 3), [...], [3, 5, (2, 3)]]
```

can you help me spot the mistake ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: ohh thank you i didnt saw this one. ill delete it.